# Theoretical Physics Notation (Hamilton-Jacobi in the Relativistic Domain)

Tags: spacetime, relativity, notation

I am having trouble understanding how to solve some theoretical physics problems I have come across. Specifically how to convert the Hamilton-Jacobi equation:
$$(\partial_\mu S+e A_\mu)^2=m^2$$
From Minkowski-space notation to conventional form:
$$(\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}+\frac{\alpha}{r})^2-(\nabla S)^2=m^2$$
where $A_0=-\frac{\alpha}{er})$ and $A_x=A_y=A_z=0$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of what the Einstein summation convention means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that $\partial_\mu$ is shorthand for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ where $x^\mu=(t,x,y,z)$. Furthermore, it can be seen from your question that the metric convention that is used is $+ - - -$, so that $x_\mu=(t,-x,-y,-z)$. Then, one can easily write out your equation. The Einstein summation convention is used.
\begin{align}
(\partial_\mu S+eA_\mu)^2&=m^2\\
(\partial_\mu S+eA_\mu)(\partial^\mu S+eA^\mu)&=m^2\\
\partial_\mu S\partial^\mu S+e^2A_\mu A^\mu+2e\partial_\mu S A^\mu&=m^2
\end{align}

Your final equation follows pretty much trivially, once you set $A_0=-\frac{\alpha}{er}$ and $A_i=0$.

Comment: By the way, if you are unfamiliar with index notation, that is something you should probably try to understand first. Looking around on this forum could be a good start.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It was the last part of the equation I didn't figure out that the whole part is 0 if $\mu =x,y,z$. Looks like I need to brush up on Einstein notation first.